# How do you determine span and basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am presented with the question:

> Given $x_1$ = $(1,1,1)^T$ and $x_2$ = $(3,-1,3)^T$:
>
> a) Do $x_1$ and $x_2$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$? Explain
>
> b) Let $x_3$ be a third vextor in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and set X=($x_1,x_2,x_3$). What
>   conditions would X have to satisfy in order for $x_1, x_2, x_3$ to form
>   a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?
>
> c) Find a third vector $x_3$ that will extend the set {$x_1, x_2$} to a
>   basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

I think I have a vague understanding of span and basis, but have the rules laid out in the context of the problem would be very helpful. I'm unsure of how exactly to go about this problem. The book gives terrible explanations and examples. My teacher isn't much better... Can anyone help out?

Comment: Question : Can any two vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: No, you need three vectors to span $R^3$. 2 vectors in $R^3$ only represent a plane, right?  (If you tell me how to make that 'R', I'll edit mine).

Comment: Type \mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $c$ you have a couple of strategies. The most straightforward is to add a known basis to the two vectors and row reduce the matrix you get:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1&-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1& 3 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0&-4 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0& 0 &-1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 1 &-1/4 & 1/4 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Since the first three columns are dominant, the set $\{x_1,x_2,e_1\}$ is linearly independent. Of course there are many other solutions, as *every* basis can be used.

The second strategy consists in applying the fact that the orthogonal complement of the column space of $[x_1~x_2]$ is the null space of the transpose of this matrix; so we eliminate
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
that gives, as a vector spanning the null space, $y=[-1~0~1]$. Therefore also $\{x_1,x_2,y\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Why did you have *e1 e2 and e3*? Why not just *e1*?

Comment: @rphello101 Because I can't know in advance which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

a) No because two vector span a space of dimension at most two, while $\mathbb R^3$ has dimension $3$;

b) $X$, seen as a $3\times 3$ matrix, must to have non zero determinant;

c) there are infinitely many solutions which can be founded by determinantal criterion.

Comment: a) and b) are pretty straight forward, but I'm still a bit confused on c). could you perhaps add a bit more detail?

Comment: Concretely, a possible vector $x_3=(x,y,z)$ can be founded by expanding:
$\det\begin{bmatrix}
1& 3 & x\\
1&-1 & y\\
1& 3 & z\\
\end{bmatrix}\neq 0$